# Similarity between "user interactions path"

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding, user-interaction

I have to compare a set of paths and look for similarity between they. "Which one is most similar to which?" is the question that I'm trying to solve.

**Path characteristics:**

1. A path is made up by the usage order of **blocks name and actions** in the Scratch (by MIT) tool. This way, the path is made by the user interactions with the tool. Example:

   `(Block added, Motion Block);
   (Block removed, Motion Block);
   (Program Executed);`
2. There's no weight between edges.
3. It's possible to have duplicated "nodes".

I know that I need to discretize those "user decision nodes", but with that in mind, is there a best practice or well known algorithm that can help me to find some similarity or group those states by similarity? The best that I found so far is "graph similarity".

Comment: why do you need a graph? you may convert those sequences into strings and find Levenstein distance between a pair of strings that you want to find similarity for

Comment: Hi @mangusta, those insights are exactly what I'm looking for. I will take a look at your suggestion, thanks!